# How to do a flip animation between more than two UIViews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have animation code in a class that extends the UIView:

```
// Start Animation Block
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:[self superview] cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

//int nextView = currentView + 1;
// Animations
[[self superview] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
//And so I would do: [[self superview exchangeSubviewAtIndex:currentView withSubviewAtIndex:nextView];
//Doesn't work because curentView is not global... with each instance of a class it's reset to what it's instanciated to. 
//currentView++;

// Commit Animation Block
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This animation code works fine for two views. But I am trying to do this for many views. I tried by adding in a global variable (nextview index and currentView index), however this doesn't work since each custom view class has it's own instance and these variables aren't shared.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish what I want to do?

Thanks!

Edit: I would be able to do this, if I could use [self superview] to access the index of the currentview and of the nextview. Are there some methods to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Apple have a pretty good tutorial on view transitions [here](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ViewTransitions/index.html).  Other than the way they implement them you can also look at using a UINavigationController which manages a bunch of views and transitioning between them.

Essentially you need to manage the transition in the superview rather than the view - the superview can know who it's currently displaying and who's next.

Answer (score 2):

If you have pointers to the views you're trying to switch between, just call -removeFromSuperview on the "from" view and -addSubview:(the "to" view) on the superview. The transition doesn't rely on any particular method call; more or less any form of the "swap two views" approach will be animated properly.

Answer (score 1):

For those who find this question who are supporting iOS 4.0 and higher, Apple has provided a built-in API for this task:

See: [transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think a Linked List of views might be what you should think about implementing.

Comment: I have an array of views that I create in the appdelegate and I add a different array to each tab view controller. Then the controller uses that array to create uiviews with animation to toggle between them. I'm having trouble with the animation toggling...

Comment: There's no need to implement a linked list. `NSArray` is perfectly fine for that. If you're really concerned about the performance, read [this article](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/?p=27).