# FlipView Transition

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uikit

I'm currently designing an app that pulls map data from a service and renders them as pins on the MKMapView. In addition, my application has been designed using storyboards where each scene is embedded within a navigation controller. The feature I'm working on requires me to give the user the ability to toggle between a map view and table view for a given result set. To provide this functionality I've included a bar button item in the toolBar which (when pressed) should flip the current view out and a second view in.

So far I've been trying to the following code but to no avail:

```
MapListViewController *map = [[MapListViewController alloc]init];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flip animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:map.view cache:YES];

[self.mapView removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:map.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I originally got this approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238654/how-to-do-a-flip-animation-between-more-than-two-uiviews) but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

A couple more things to note:

- The flip view transition should only change the view currently displayed within the top and bottom navigation bars.
- Presenting the new view modally isn't an option because I will lose site of my navigation controller.
- The view/view controller responsible for displaying the result set in a list format (i.e. UITableView) is contained within a single xib file where as the rest of the application sits within a storyboard.

**Question**

What is wrong with my current implementation? How should it be modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used your method but I did implement flipping some views using a UIView class method. It was very easy and straightforward. Refer to the docs for other options.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.firstVC.view toView:self.secondVC.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // add any completion code here if needed.
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this links may help you

[Flip View Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843534/flip-view-iphone)

[how to implement an iPhone view transition animation with both flipping and scaling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755492/how-to-implement-an-iphone-view-transition-animation-with-both-flipping-and-scal)

Hope it helps you . Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi implementing some thing like this should help you

To Push use this..

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

For Pop use this

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```